# Problema con sentencia preparada SELECT

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin, mariadb

soy nuevo en la programación y estoy teniendo un problema que me tiene loco con la pagina de inicio de sesión de un ejercicio que estoy haciendo. El problema es que hago una consulta preparada para seleccionar las filas que coincidan con el email y la clave y no pasa absolutamente nada. He buscado en miles de foros y de verdad es imposible. Les dejo el código para que me puedan ayudar

```
<?php
require_once('connection.php');

if (isset($_POST['email'])){
    $userEmail = $_POST['email'];
    echo "$userEmail<br>";
    $userPass =($_POST['pass']);
    echo "$userPass<br>";
}


$stmtLogin2 = mysqli_stmt_init($dbconnect);
if(mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmtLogin2, "SELECT id, nombre, apellido, nivel FROM tblacceso WHERE email= ? AND pass= ?")){
    echo 'paso prepare <br>';
}
if (mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmtLogin2,"ss",$userEmail, $userPass)){
    echo 'paso bind_param <br>';
}
if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmtLogin2)){
    echo 'paso excute<br>';
}
if (mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmtLogin2)){
    echo 'paso store_result<br>';
}
if (mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmtLogin2, $userId, $userNombre, $userApellido, $userNivel)){
    echo $userId."  ".$userNombre."  ".$userApellido."  ".$userNivel;
    echo 'paso bind_result<br>';

mysqli_stmt_close($stmtLogin2);

mysqli_close($dbconnect);

?>
```

Hasta aquí, las variables que recojo siempre están vacias, hay mas código pero todo depende de este paso. Estoy usando Xampp la versión mas reciente.

**EDIT**: Cambie algunas de las cosas que me comentaron, pero hasta el momento cuando leo las variables del bind_result, estan vacias. Además probe una sentencia de INSERT usando las mismas funciones y funciona perfectamente

Comment: Hola @andr16, Bienvenido a stackoverflow. Te recomiendo que te dirijas a la pagina oficial de php [Aqui](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php), espero que te sirva.

Comment: Ya lo he hecho, me leí todo lo referente a mysqli pero no logró resolver mi problema. De hecho ya probé hacer un insert y si lo pude hacer, el problema es el select

Comment: Te sobran los paréntesis del WHERE.

Comment: Esas han sido medidas desesperadas, pero sin ellos tampoco funciona, he probado con comillas simples, dobles, con o sin parentesis. Incluso acabo de copiar y pegar la sentencia en la consola de SQL de phpmyadmin y cambie los '?' por los valores y la consulta si funciona. La idea era probar algun error de los campos o del nombre de la tabla.

Comment: @andr16 que tienes en el archivo `require_once('connection.php');` .puedes editar ?

Comment: @JosueSantana Si puedo editar, en ese archivo se encuentra la conexion a la base de datos. Los datos como el usuario, la contraseña, la base de datos y el mysqli_connect

Comment: @andr16 tienes que publicar lo que tienes en tu formulario. **Ejemplo: tu html que es el formulario, conexion.php y tu código que nos mostrarte al final **, para así ayudar te en lo que necesitas ;)

Answer (score 0):

> En el manual de php se encuentra esta informacion:
>
> sqli_store_result ( mysqli $link [, int $option ] ) : mysqli_result
>
> link Sólo estilo por procediminetos: Un identificador de enlace
>   devuelto por mysqli_connect() o mysqli_init()

Tu tienes esto:

> mysqli_store_result($dbconnect);

¿No debería ser?

```
mysqli_store_result($stmtLogin);
```

Comment: Si, tienes toda la razón, de hecho ya lo corregí pero sigo sin resultados. Los valores de las columnas que estoy consultando me llegan nulos, es como si no hubiese ningún registro. Voy a editar el codigo para mostrar como esta ahora, sin resultados